# Window.external is giving error "Unable to get property "xxx" of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I am doing a window application in vs 2013 c# with an embedded webbrower. When window.external.xxx('1') is called from html displayed in the browser I am getting error

> "Unable to get property "xxx" of undefined or null reference".

Webbrowser control version is 11.0.9600.17631. Any idea would be much appreciated.

```
<input type="button" id="A1" value="good" onclick='window.exteranl.xxx("1");' />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably the typo `exteranl`

Comment: my mistake correct code is <input type="button" id="A1" value="good" onclick='window.external.xxx("1")' />. it is not working with correct spellings.

Answer (score 1):

got the answer. you have to add

webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;

thanks Soner and any body else who has read and attempted to answer.

thanks